# Merge multiple dataset to create one histogram in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

There are three pairs representing the start and stop point of three horizontal lines. How to create a histogram that shows the overlapping segment counts? Assuming `bin=[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, ... 3.0]`
[image]

The histogram function from `matplotlib` treats these pairs as three different datasets.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = (1.5, 2.8)
b = (1.9, 3.0)
c = (1.6, 2.1)

pair_list = [a,b,c]
pair_data = []
for pair in pair_list:
    pair_data.append(np.arange(pair[0],pair[1],0.1))

plt.hist(pair_data)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Change `pair_data.append(...)` to `pair_data.extend(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex said, changing append to extend does the trick. Just make sure to get the right amount of bins to get the result you want (default is 10).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = (1.5, 2.8)
b = (1.9, 3.0)
c = (1.6, 2.1)

pair_list = [a,b,c]
pair_data = []
for pair in pair_list:
    pair_data.extend(np.arange(pair[0],pair[1],0.1))

plt.hist(pair_data,bins=int((np.max(pair_data)-np.min(pair_data))*10)+1)
# (max-min)/binsize + 1 gives you bins of width binsize
plt.show()
```